# Tesseract unable to recognize numbers from a simple image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, captcha

This is the image and I'm trying to extract "3158"

[image]

And this is the code

> ```
> import cv2
> import tesseract
>     
> img = cv2.imread('cropped.png')
> convert_to_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
> print (convert_to_string)
> ```

But unfortunately it failed to print anything

I've tried

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config=' --psm 1 --oem 3)
```

and

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config=' --psm 6)
```

But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try to binarize the image first, Tesseract does not work well if the font does not stand out clearly from the background. Since there's a gradient in the background, you may get some first good results with adaptive thresholding preprocessing:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('cropped.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img_bin = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    img_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 10
)

img_bin = cv2.cvtColor(img_bin, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

convert_to_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_bin)
print(convert_to_string)
```